# Dynamycally loading resources in Monogame framework

Tags: c#, monogame

Is there any generic way of loading resources runtime in monogame.
Like loading Texture2d would be like this

```
        Texture2D.FromStream(graphixDevice,someStream)
```

is there something like 
            `Resource<Texture2D>.LoadFromStream(stream);`

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way of loading assets is through [`ContentManager`](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=T_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Content_ContentManager). The `Load<T>` method is generic, but requires the asset be processed with the [Content Pipeline](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Using_The_Pipeline_Tool). The asset is optimized and stored in a fast-to-load format along with all dependencies (textures for model, etc.).

The type-specific `FromStream` methods exist only for the few cases where the content can't be preprocessed, eg. user-generated content.